# wamp cannot load mysqli extension

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, phpmyadmin

WAMP installed fine, no problems, BUT...

When going to phpMyAdmin, I get the error from phpMyAdmin as follows:

```
Cannot load mysqli extension. Please check your PHP configuration
```

Also, phpMyAdmin documentation explains this error message as follows:

> To connect to a MySQL server, PHP needs a set of MySQL functions
>   called "MySQL extension". This extension may be part of the PHP
>   distribution (compiled-in), otherwise it needs to be loaded
>   dynamically. Its name is probably mysql.so or php_mysql.dll.
>   phpMyAdmin tried to load the extension but failed. Usually, the
>   problem is solved by installing a software package called "PHP-MySQL"
>   or something similar.

Finally, the apache_error.log file has the following PHP warnings (see the mySQL warning):

```
PHP Warning: Zend Optimizer does not support this version of PHP - please upgrade to the latest version of Zend Optimizer in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning: Zend Platform does not support this version of PHP - please upgrade to the latest version of Zend Platform in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning: Zend Debug Server does not support this version of PHP - please upgrade to the latest version of Zend Debug Server in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning: gd wrapper does not support this version of PHP - please upgrade to the latest version of gd wrapper in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning: java wrapper does not support this version of PHP - please upgrade to the latest version of java wrapper in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning: mysql wrapper does not support this version of PHP - please upgrade to the latest version of mysql wrapper in Unknown on line 0
```

So, for some reason PHP is not recognizing the mysql extension.

Anyone know why? Any solution or workaround?

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 19):

I deleted the PHP in program files ad everything started working , the problem that there two installations of pHp

Comment: Me, too. You can check on phpinfo() which php.ini is being loaded.

Comment: I had another install of PHP with Apache 2.2. I uninstalled PHP via the Programs and Features control panel AND deleted the PHP folders I found in the C: root directory and Program Files.

Comment: Same for me, delete the phpinfo file :)

Answer (score 7):

I tried many solutions, and none worked for me. I tried the following solutions:

- Restart wampserver
- Reinstall wampserver
- restart machine
- and all other solutions mentioned in this question.

However, none of these worked. Then I found that my PHPMyAdmin was not working in chrome and was working in firefox. So I tried clearing cache, restarting browser etc, but still it would not work.

Then I deleted all the files from `C:\wamp\tmp` and then tried again, and it works. I am not sure why it works, but here is what I think. The session was cached and not getting cleared. So as soon as I deleted all files in this directory all the sessions were deleted and hence it worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

First, make sure that the `php.ini` file is loading the `mysqli` extension.
If you are using WAMPServer, click on the icon in the system tray, go to `PHP` -> `PHP Extensions` and make sure it is checked.  If not, go into the `php.ini` file and make sure that the line: `extension=php_mysqli.dll` is uncommented (eg, remove the `;` if it exists).  If that line does not exist, add it.

If this still does not work, double check that the right `php.ini` file is being loaded.
To do so, view your phpinfo() ([Here](http://localhost/?phpinfo=1) for WAMPServer).  Scroll down to the `Loaded Configuration File` row and see which `php.ini` is being loaded.`Make sure it is the right file.  If you're using WAMPServer, it should be`(WAMP INSTALL FOLDER)\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin\php.ini`.  By default, it is`C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin\php.ini`.

If a different `php.ini` file is being loaded, just rename it to something else so that PHP will try and find the file somewhere else.  There should be a way to specify which on eyou want to use, but I forget exactly how to do that...

If this still doesn't work... Try messing around with phpMyAdmin's settings, or using another answer, but I'm afraid I can't help beyond this.

Answer (score 2):

I was running WAMP with two PHP versions 1) 5.2.9 and 2) 5.2.13.

As per site requirement i needed to change PHP version to 5.2.9 from 5.2.13. after swapping PHP version, error was "mysqli extension is missing". after debugging long time i get to know it was due to wrong "extension_dir" path in php.ini file.

So i changed its value:

Old:  "extension_dir" c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.2.13/ext/

New:  "extension_dir" c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.2.9/ext/

Restarted All services in wamp server, then it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had WAMP server installed. All was working fine. Then one day I restarted my computer and it just stopped working! I tried desperately going through all help posts and doing them but nothing worked.

What they usually suggest you do is, first go to your php.ini file and make sure your 'extension_dir' is properly set. Then to make sure these two lines are not commented (remove the  ; infront):
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll

Then some suggested that I download fresh copies of these two files but none worked. I also tried uninstalling everything (php/mysql/apache) and reinstalled fresh copies of WAMP server several times but with no luck.

Finally I managed to find an alternative solution. I switched to 'easyphp' (http://www.easyphp.org/). This is something very similar to WAMP. First I made backups of my sql databases so I can reload them on the new installation.

Then I installed 'easyphp' and everything seems to work fine. I reloaded my sql databases from my backup and now things are back to normal.

I hope someone suffering from a similar prob. will find this useful. If someone has really found a fix to make WAMP server work. Pls do be kind enough to post it here so many will benefit.

Answer (score 1):

in wampserver go to php.ini. open the file and uncomment extension=msql.dll by removing semicolon(;) for respective operating sytem.

Answer (score 1):

Also setup the mysql password:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD('your_password');
```

And the phpmyadmin mysql password in config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your_password';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add in your php.ini:

```
[PHP_MCRYPT]
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
[PHP_MYSQL]
extension=php_mysql.dll
[PHP_MYSQLI]
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to chime in on this one. Using Wamp Server 2.0, and using Zend Studio with Zend debugger for development.

I wasn't able as of yet (will get back to it at some point) to get the zend debugger working with php 5.3. So in wamp I loaded an earlier php version, 5.2.11. I was getting the same error when acessing php my admin.

What I had to do was change the php.ini file value for "extension_dir" to `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.2.11/ext/` to match the version of php I was using. After that it was all good.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, with wamp. Try to exchange your current version of php.ini with a backup. There is one in: `wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0phpForApache.txt`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and spent 2 hours trying all the solutions online, none worked.

Tried this, and it woked:

Change

> mysql.default_host =

to

> mysql.default_host = localhost

and restart WAMP. pay attention if you are using mysqli or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. When I increased the script memory size and enabled E_ALL then restarted the server, I got that error in phpmyadmin. All I had to do to fix it was restart my computer!

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem for a long time.
 Tried all I've read on forums and this finally worked for me:
Open your php.ini (I assume you've got the good one that is loaded...) and find this line
mysqli.default_port = 3306
change for 
mysqli.default_port = 80
Restart all services
Go to localhost/phpmyadmin -> won't work
Reopen the php.ini file and retype this 
mysqli.default_port = 3306
Restart all services
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this, after searching all logs/internet/every non-normal things.
You have to register dl by:

Through application:

```
WAMP -> PHP settings -> enable dl
```

or

```
# php.ini #

; Whether or not to enable the dl() function.  The dl() function does NOT work
; properly in multithreaded servers, such as IIS or Zeus, and is automatically
; disabled on them.
; http://php.net/enable-dl
enable_dl = On
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed WampServer, and faced same problem. I have found solution, that works for me, it is ridiculously simple.

1. Disable PHP extension `php_mysqli`.
2. Restart WampServer, visit local `phpmyadmin`.
3. Enable `php_mysqli` back.
4. Repeat step 2.

After few page refreshes, remaining errors plates (about `MySQL` and `sqli`) had gone.

Answer (score 0):

i tried hard by
installing the wamp again and again,
by checking the php.ini file,
by restarting the machine,
by replacing the index.php file,

but none works.
then i go to the wamp/temp and deleted all files and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had path variable in windows set to some random version of php.

The fix was to update it and set it to the folder within my wampserver installation:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.38
```

Then I realized this is wrong also for my specific case, and I should actually be running the script from within vagrant. Live and learn.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because of a different reason:

Check the PHP Error Log(Get from the Wamp Tray -> PHP -> PHP Error Log. 
I had a syntax error in the php.ini file while I was editing the file. 
Check the log and clear the error. This will open your PhpMyAdmin properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your phpForApache.ini file's extensions. This file should be same as your php.ini file.